# My NextJs front-end can't store the cookie sent from the server side

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, next.js, cors

I'm trying to deploy my app to production, everything is fine except for something no less important.

Everything works perfectly for me locally, but when I pass it to production it happens that when I log in it does not store the cookie. I am using a domain for the front and a different one for the back.

On the server side I am using Express, below I leave my Cors configuration:

```js
app.use(cors({
    origin: ['https://myappserverside.app'],
    credentials: true,
}));
```

This is how I have it on the front side with Next.Js:

```js
const handleSubmit = async (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const res = await axios.post('https://myappclientside.app/login', login, { withCredentials: true });
            if(res.status === 200){
                toast.success('Logged in');
                router.push('/profile');   
            }
        } catch(error){
           toast.error("Can't login")
        }
    };
```

On the other hand, I show you how the server sends the cookie:

```js
const token = jwt.sign({
            exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
            id: id,
        }, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

        const serialized = serialize('token', token, {
            httpOnly: true,
            sameSite: 'none',
            secure: true,
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
        });
        res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', serialized);
        return res.json('Logged in');
```

I hope someone can help me because I can't find the solution. Thank you very much for reading!

**UPDATE**

If I look for the requests made in "Networks" in the browser, I see that it correctly receives the cookie. The problem is still that it does not store it.

Comment: "almacenate"? Do you mean "store"?

Comment: Exactly, sorry if I expressed myself badly. I need to store the cookie when users login, in local works fine, but when I deploy it between two different domains, it happens that it is not stored.

Comment: AFAICT, there's nothing amiss in the way you set the cookie. One reason for the browser to reject is an invalid cookie value. What does the value look like?

Comment: It is a very long alphanumeric value created with the Crypto library. Did you say try a smaller one? On localhost it works perfectly. The strange thing is that the cookie is not stored, but it does bring me the data of the url parameters, which I get by decoding the cookie. It is very strange what happens. I have checked everything, even the privacy part of all my browsers and nothing.

Comment: @MEVG were you able resolve the issue? My case is similar to yours i m able to get the cookie, but when i host them on 2 different places, i m not able to get it